# Nested Try Catch Logic

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I'd just like to confirm the logic of this nested try-catch block:

```
    Try
        Using dbConn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = strConnStr}
            dbConn.Open()
            'Prepare transaction

            Try
                ' Execute transaction
            Catch ex As Exception
                Try
                    ' Transaction rollback
                Catch ex2 As SqlException
                    ' ...
                End Try
            Finally
                dbConn.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' ...
    End Try
```

1. If the database connection fails before the transaction is executed (2nd Try-Catch block), the exception will be caught by the first catch block and will no longer proceed further right?
2. Is the case in nested Try-Catch blocks, the exceptions are contained inside their own try-catch block? Ie: If the transaction execution fails, it calls the 2nd catch block (which initiates rollback), but it won't call the first catch block yes? Similarly, if the transaction rollback occurs, it will only call its corresponding catch block and not the first two?

Comment: Exceptions will not bubble up as long as they match the exception type defined by the Catch line(s). You can rethrow the error from within the catch block to bubble it if that's desired.  Intentionally malforming your connection string should illuminate what happens (along with breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

when an exception throws, it will be passed to closest catch block Corresponding to try block to handle it. if there is not any catch block to handle the exception or if Corresponding catch block throws exception, it comes out, if there is any try/catch block, exception passes to parent catch block and so on.